# Can Memcached use the App Engine instance's own memory?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, memcached

Google is obsoleting its own memcache, but with PHP 7.2  runtime of the standard App Engine environment Memcached is available.

Is it possible to use the instance's own memory with Memcached? If so then what port should one use when calling addServer()?  (I guess the server is localhost.)

Answer (score -1):

I understand you wish to implement a caching solution for your App Engine application.

For your App Engine instance's caching needs, we recommend you use Memorystore[1] as it is integrated in the Google Cloud Platform specifically for the use case of caching. Memorystore for Redis[2] is the recommended version as of now, as Memorystore for Memcached is still in beta, however it is still an available option[3].

Please do keep in mind that Memorystore does not provide a free tier, Memorystore pricing can be found on the public documentation[4].

Memcached integration outside of GCP is not an officially supported GCP product, so in this regard I do not know enough about memcached to provide assistance in this matter.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/memorystore

[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/using-memorystore

[3] https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/memcached/creating-managing-instances

[4] https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/pricing